# Query is taking too much time to run

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query with me.
What it does is that it fetches the bug id's and time taken to complete these bugs within a date range and other conditions given.
This is taking too much time to process.
Table bugs, bugs_activity consists of large set of data.

```
my $query = "SELECT COUNT(b.bug_id) as cntBugId, SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(ba.bug_when,b.creation_ts)))/60
                 AS time_taken FROM techzilla.bugs b, techzilla.bugs_activity ba WHERE b.bug_id=ba.bug_id
                 AND b.bug_status='RESOLVED' AND b.resolution='FIXED' AND ba.added='RESOLVED' AND b.creation_ts
                 BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' AND b.bug_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT b.bug_id
                 FROM techzilla.bugs b, techzilla.bugs_activity ba, techzilla.user_group_map_stats u,
                 techzilla.profiles p WHERE ba.bug_id=b.bug_id AND b.bug_status='RESOLVED' AND b.resolution='FIXED'
                 AND ba.added='RESOLVED' AND b.creation_ts BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' AND p.userid=b.assigned_to
                 AND p.userid=u.user_id AND u.group_id='$groupId')";
```

Query run :

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(b.bug_id) as cntBugId, SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(ba.bug_when,b.creation_ts)))/60 AS time_taken FROM techzilla.bugs b, techzilla.bugs_activity ba WHERE b.bug_id=ba.bug_id AND b.bug_status='RESOLVED' AND b.resolution='FIXED' AND ba.added='RESOLVED' AND b.creation_ts BETWEEN '2020-12-17 00:00:00' AND '2021-01-09 23:59:59' AND b.bug_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT b.bug_id FROM techzilla.bugs b, techzilla.bugs_activity ba, techzilla.user_group_map_stats u, techzilla.profiles p WHERE ba.bug_id=b.bug_id AND b.bug_status='RESOLVED' AND b.resolution='FIXED' AND ba.added='RESOLVED' AND b.creation_ts BETWEEN '2020-12-17 00:00:00' AND '2021-01-09 23:59:59' AND p.userid=b.assigned_to AND p.userid=u.user_id AND u.group_id='106');
+----------+--------------+
| cntBugId | time_taken   |
+----------+--------------+
|    12249 | 1739767.0167 | 
+----------+--------------+
1 row in set (7.74 sec)
```

Table `bugs` consists of many entries with a primary key bug_id.
Table `bugs_activity` contains the changes made by a person to the bug stored in `bugs` table.
The query goes through all bugs listed in `bugs` table based on the bug creatiion dates e.t.c

Each bug is belonging to a group which has a unique id.

Any way i could make this query run faster?
By join or something.

Comment: You should not use variable interpolation in your query strings, as you leave your code open to injection, and other errors. Use placeholders. (Assuming this is DBI). That may be unrelated to performance issues.

Comment: @TLP ok got it! but i really need the query to run a bit more faster.

Comment: This looks like you want a group by instead of the subquery.

Comment: @Akhilpaul . . . I would suggest that. you provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the query should do.  Formatting your code *as SQL text* in the question would also be helpful.  You should also avoid munging the query with constants and learn to use parameters.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Please check

Comment: @clamp could you please explain what you are proposing.

Comment: Take the SELECT clause of your main query, the FROM clause of your subquery and GROUP BY  u.group_id (You don't even need the group by if you filter by group_id. Take that as a start for optimization.

Comment: Use JOIN instead of IN.  Have `INDEX(bug_status, resolution, creation_ts)` (in that order).

Answer (score 1):

It's very unlikely that the fact you're using Perl has any bearing on this problem (and, of course, you can demonstrate that by running the query in the `mysql` command line program instead of through a Perl program).

I recommend reading the MySQL [documentation on optimising queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-optimization.html). I suspect you'll end up adding indexes to your tables.